# Loading an ASP.Net page inside another ASP.Net page using Ajax

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, jquery, postback

I managed to load a distinct page inside a div in another page using jquery ajax. The problem I am encountering is that when I click a button inside this sub page, it cause a postback to the whole parent page. How can I force it to just refresh the panel it resides in?

One more thing. I am not sure I am doing the right thing, but the parent page has its own form with runat=server settings, while the secondary page that is loaded inside the div has its own form. I cannot remove the form from the latter because it causes an error.

I have seen some asp.net ajax tutorials but they do not deal with loading sub pages that havbe their own .net controls. Can anyone guide me to some good tutorial?

Thanks!

Comment: Load the HTML into a variable and use ajax to write the string to desired location

Comment: Loading a partial into a page, really makes it a PART of that page, so anything it does at the page level (like submit) will work on that entity (the page DOM) in this case.  You would need to intercept the submit to make it work ONLY on the portion you need impacted.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss - Yes I got that far. My problem is to intercept the submit command.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a  empty with an Id for example : **ajaxDiv**

Then you create a jquery script like this :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    // Called at the loading of a page
        $(document).ready(function () {
    //here you execute an ajax function 
    $.ajax({
                        url: 'the url to retrieve data as string ex : /Webservice/Test',
                        type: 'get',
                        async: true of false,
//if the request is successful, you load the content of your div with the strings you loaded
                        success: function (data) {
                           $("ajaxDiv").html(data);

                        }
                    });

     });
    </script>
```

the tips is to load your page into the ajax request.

Comment: Thanks Giu Do. That code is similar to what I am using to load the sub page. But how do I make the controls in the sub page affect that page only (and not the host page)?

Comment: Do you use ASP.NET MVC ? because with it you can define "partial views" with forms inside and a model which is independant of the host page.

If not then try a control to reload only the div ajaxDiv, so you need to call/implement the function also in the partial view.

Comment: I am new to ASP.net and I am not familiar with MVC. I come from a classic ASP background and I when using AJAX I would pass the command with a query string and reload the partial view. I understand ASP.Net works differently.

Answer (score 0):

OK, since you are using jQuery, let's set up that event manipulation.
I assume the following markup:

```
<button type="submit" id="mySubmitButtonId">Submit</button>
```

Then, on my page I have the following javascript:

```
$("#mySubmitButtonId").click(function(event) { 
  event.preventDefault(); 
  // do here what you want to do instead including refresh of a section via ajax
});
```